# Inserting HTML into div classes

Tags: jquery, var, css-selectors

I have a series of divs being displayed via jquery with `var` and then the divs get repositioned via `nth-child` when the browser width changes.

Here is the var code that displays the div.

```
var theDivs={
"div1":$("<div />").addClass("test"),
"div2":$("<div />").addClass("test2"),
"div3":$("<div />").addClass("test3"),
"div4":$("<div />").addClass("test4")
};
```

So I'm creating the 4 divs and then adding the series of "test" classes. This works great, but instead of just adding a div class name, I would like to be able to add some html, much like the `.after` code.. eg:

```
$( '.somedivclass' ).after( '<div class="test"><a href="#"></a></div>');
```

Here is the full example of my current code (resize the HTML window to see the divs nth-child position change):

http://jsfiddle.net/EUqEm/85/

So yeah, I would like to be able to add my own html code within the test divs while making it work with the current code I have (see my jsfiddle) where the divs change position on browser width change.

Any input or help would be awesome and a working jquery would be even better! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to add the HTML content to your `div` elements.

```
var theDivs={
    "div1":$("<div />").addClass("test").html('<span>RED</span>'),
    "div2":$("<div />").addClass("test2").html('<span>BLUE</span>'),
    "div3":$("<div />").addClass("test3").html('<span>GREEN</span>'),
    "div4":$("<div />").addClass("test4").html('<span>PURPLE</span>')
};
```

To ensure that the content gets removed upon resize, you can use [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

```
$("#wrapper div").attr("class","inner").empty();
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5REk/3/)

Comment: this works for the most part Ruben, but when you resize the html window the span text still stays there, when it should be removed.. if you could get the span text to remove on browser width change like the current divs, that would be great!

Comment: When exactly should the HTML be added to the `div` elements and when should it be removed?

Comment: well the divs get removed and re added for different browser widths (try resizing the html window in jsfiddle) but when you resize the window the divs get removed and re added for the different browser widths, but the span text just stays. so the span text should correspond with the divs in terms of being added / removed.. or "moved"... :)

Comment: I updated my answer and the jsfiddle example. Take a look and see if that is the result you desire.

Comment: Hey Ruben, I have an offer for you regarding these jquery browser width div codes that you did, e-mail me if your interested... ianhorstb@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
var theDivs={
"div1":$("<div />").addClass("test").text('Some text'),
"div2":$("<div />").addClass("test2").text('Some text'),
"div3":$("<div />").addClass("test3").text('Some text'),
"div4":$("<div />").addClass("test4").text('Some text')
};
```